# Android : Integrating Google Chrome Cast Library

Tags: android, git, chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to build a Cast sender app and have been trying to follow the example of the [reference app](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android), particularly using the CastCompanionLibrary (CCL).

Is there an easier way of integrating the companion library without having to do all the mundane steps indicated in the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender)? They haven't published a maven/gradle distribution, and cloning the library into my repo has led to some problems, primarily because it leads to an empty directory in the Github repo, as indicated in the snapshot below:
[image]

I tried downloading the zip file from the releases tab, added it to my project as a sub-module in Android Studio. The project is now not able to run, as it seems to mess with my run configuration (Run/Debug buttons are greyed out).

I'm a bit at a loss why a library that is meant to make cast integration easier is anything but. The documentation is buried into a PDF file too, instead of the more traditional readme.

Comment: Is this a question or a complaint? You can file an issue in the github repo if you want to see changes, but it's mainly just declaring dependencies. What I like to do, which could be easier, is just open up the sample apps and build off/modify that. Doing so, all the necessary dependencies and setup is already taken care of.

Comment: @Andy, It's a question. Like you, naturally the first thing I did was to check out the sample up and try to mirror the same setup, but ran into the problems I've described above. 

The main thing I wanna find out is how integrating the library as exemplified in the sample app is supposed to be shared with other devs without having them clone local copies of the library. 

Anyway, I have created an issue on the github repo.

Comment: Why don't you check out the CCL, run "./gradlew build" and then grab the resulting aar file and then use that in your other project, if that is all you want to do? In addition, the docs is in PDF for a good reason, it has a large number of pages, cross references, images, etc so do you really expect that to be part of the README file there? Is there an issue with opening a PDF file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we can use locally deployed AARs as a workaround in the meantime:

1. Clone the CCL project into a directory outside of the main project
2. Build the CCL project to generate AAR files: `cd <CCL Dir>; ./gradlew build`
3. Import CCL into main project as a module. File->New->Import AAR/JAR
4. Configure your dependencies to reflect CCL's. Apparently dependencies from an AAR library do not propagate up to the main project's build.gradle:

   `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.1.0'
   compile project(':CastCompanionLibrary-debug')
   compile project(':CastCompanionLibrary-release')`

Note: you can also throw the AAR files into your 'libs' folder and add the following to build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
compile 'com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary:CastCompanionLibrary-debug@aar'
```

...